# Efficient method to create NxN similarity/distance matrix in python

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

I need to create an NxN similarity matrix in python where N = 943.
I initially used sklearns implementation of cosine_similarity, but now I need to use a much more complex and non-standard distance metric.

Good afternoon,
I have a user-movie dataframe (NaN's in the table indicate that the user has not rated those movies)

```
| movie_id | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
|----------|---|---|---|---|---|
| user_id  |   |   |   |   |   |
| 1        | 1 | 1 | NaN | 4 | 5 |
| 2        | NaN | 1 | 1 | 5 | 5 |
| 3        | 4 | NaN | 4 | 1 | 2 |
```

I need to apply 3 individual functions to the user-movie dataframe: proximity, impact, and popularity. 
The final similarity between 2 users is given by the product of proximity, impact, and popularity. 
Now the tricky part is that I only need to apply the above 3 functions for the "co-rated" items for each user. So for example, while calculating the similarity of user1 and user2, we should only consider movie_ids 2, 4 and 5.

Now I will define exactly what the 3 functions should do.

0. First I define a helper method called "agreement"
   Given 2 ratings from 2 users, this function returns True iff both ratings are on the same side of the median. In our case, the median is 2.5. Else False.

```
def agreement(rating1: int, rating2: int) -> bool:
    if ((rating1 > 2.5 and rating2 < 2.5) or (rating1 < 2.5 and rating2 > 2.5)):
        return False 
    else:
        True
```

1. Proximity
   Given 2 ratings from 2 users, this function simply calculates the absolute difference IF the 2 ratings are in agreement. If the ratings are not in agreement, then a penalty is applied.

```
def proximity(rating1: int, rating2: int) -> float: 
    if(agreement(rating1, rating2)):
        dist = np.absolute(rating1 - rating2)
    else: 
        dist = 2 * np.absolute(rating1 - rating2)
    prox = ((2*(rating_max - rating_min) + 1) - dist) ** 2
    return prox
```

2. Impact
   Given 2 ratings from 2 users, this function calculates an impact_score if the 2 ratings are in agreement. If the 2 ratings are not in agreement, then it returns 1/impact_score

```
def impact(rating1: int, rating2: int) -> float: 
    impact_score = (np.absolute(rating1 - rating_median) + 1) * (np.absolute(rating2 - rating_median) + 1)
    if(agreement(rating1, rating2)):
        return impact_score 
    else: 
        return 1/impact_score
```

3. Popularity. 
   Given 2 ratings from 2 users and the mean rating of a given movie_id(mu_k), this method calculates a pop_score iff the 2 ratings are both greater(or less) than the mean rating of the given movie.

```
def popularity(rating1: int, rating2: int, mu_k) -> float: 
    pop = 1
    if((rating1 > mu_k and rating2 > mu_k) or (rating1 < mu_k and rating2 < mu_k)):
        pop = 1 + ((rating1 + rating2)/2 - mu_k)**2
    return pop
```

The final similarity matrix should look like this:

```
#           0          1          2
#0   1.000000  60.972245  12.761905
#1  60.972245   1.000000   9.790476
#2  12.761905   9.790476   1.000000
```

The problem is my current implementation is extremely slow. It takes me roughly 1.5 hours to compute the matrix for N=943.

I currently loop over each cell of the NxN matrix and individually apply all 3 functions (Current implementation code: https://pastebin.com/zfcyBhJz).

So I wanted to know if there is a quicker and more efficient way of generating the required similarity matrix given the 3 functions to be used?

Comment: Your function seems to be applied to individual elements in the array. Consider vectorizing them for better performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `numpyp.ma.MaskedArray`, and give full play to the broadcast at the same time, you can get very good performance.

First get the `values` of df:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan


ratings = np.array([[1., 1., nan, 4., 5.],
                    [nan, 1., 1., 5., 5.],
                    [4., nan, 4., 1., 2.]])
# ratings = df_ratings.values
```

Convert to `MaskedArray`:

```
from numpy.ma import masked_invalid


ratings = masked_invalid(ratings)
# masked_array(
#   data=[[1.0, 1.0, --, 4.0, 5.0],
#         [--, 1.0, 1.0, 5.0, 5.0],
#         [4.0, --, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0]],
#   mask=[[False, False,  True, False, False],
#         [ True, False, False, False, False],
#         [False,  True, False, False, False]],
#   fill_value=1e+20)
```

Calculate the negative of `agrement` of all ratings between each pair of users:

```
temp = ratings - 2.5
not_agreements = temp[:, None] * temp[None] < 0
# Equivalent to
# from numpy.ma import masked_array
# not_argeements = masked_array([masked_array([(i - 2.5) * (j - 2.5) < 0 for j in ratings]) for i in ratings])
```

Similarly, calculate all `proximity`, `impact` and `popularity`, here I assume that `rating_max`, `rating_min` and `rating_median` are all scalars:

```
dist = np.abs(ratings[:, None] - ratings[None])
dist[not_agreements] *= 2
prox = ((2 * (rating_max - rating_min) + 1) - dist) ** 2

temp = np.abs(ratings - rating_median) + 1
impact_score = temp[:, None] * temp[None]
impact_score[not_agreements] = 1 / impact_score[not_agreements]

mu_k = ratings.mean(0)
temp = ratings - mu_k
shape = ratings.shape
pop = np.ones(shape[:1] + shape)
mask = temp[:, None] * temp[None] > 0
pop[mask] += ((temp[:, None] + temp[None]) / 2)[mask] ** 2
```

Multiply them and sum them along the last axis, then set the value on the diagonal to 1, and finally get the result you want:

```
similarity_matrix = (prox * impact_score * pop).sum(-1)
similarity_matrix[np.diag_indices_from(similarity_matrix)] = 1

similarity_matrix_df = pd.DataFrame(similarity_matrix, index=df_ratings.index, columns=df_ratings.index)
```

After testing, the running time of your traversal method is similar to that of my method in your example, but with the expansion of the array, the running time of your method increases very fast. When the shape of the array reaches (48, 50), it takes up to 10s, while my vectorization method takes only 0.06s.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the amazingly detailed answer! Indeed I forgot to provide some values. rating_max = 5, rating_min = 0 and rating_median = 2.5. However, for this set of values, your proposed solution does not output the same final similarity table. After running your code, I get this as my final table ( https://pastebin.com/45adMWwp).

Comment: I just realized that the output matrix in my post is not actually correct for this given example. I have updated the post to reflect the new output matrix. I have also written a small file which compares your implementation vs mine (https://pastebin.com/hXCRFF2T)

Comment: @RahulKalaria The else statement of your function `agreement` does not return `True`. In fact, it finally returns `None`. Are you sure there is no problem?

Comment: indeed you are correct. I am used to Scala so I thought Python would just return whatever is on the last line. 
After fixing that error, both our solutions do produce the same result! Of course with the added benefit of yours being exponentially faster. Thanks so much for the help!